# Adding values to Map from a File

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to iterate through a file that has key/value pairs and put them into a Map.

The file contains values like so:

```
forward 5
up 4
down 3
down 6
forward 4
...
```

Here is my code:

```java
       private static void depthPosition() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/WorkAcc/Desktop/file.txt"));
        String lines;
        Map<String, Integer> instructions = new HashMap<>();
        String [] pair;

        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           pair = lines.split(" ");
           instructions.put(pair[0], Integer.valueOf(pair[1]));
        }
        System.out.println(instructions);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the Map called `instructions` is not adding new values from the file, it stops at size 3, not sure why.
Would appreciate some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Does the file have blank or commented lines?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Hi, no it desn't

Comment: Does the lines have multiples spaces? What exactly does the third line of the file contain?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Nope,  just what I stated above, repeated about 1000 times

Comment: Do you know that if a line repeats key, the map overwrites the value?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Ah, perhaps that's my problem!  What data structure would you recommend I use to store the above data?

Comment: it depends on your needs, How do you want to use the information read?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Once I store the above data, I want to read it in order and do calculations based on the first parameter eg if forward then I add to the number, if down then I subtract from the number etc

Comment: In such a case, my suggestion is to use a list of 'commands' and do the mapping from line to command.

Comment: *Once I store the above data, I want to read it in order and do calculations based on the first parameter eg if forward then I add to the number, if down then I subtract from the number etc* That is important information that should be included in your question.

Comment: Hint: the real answer here: when you don't understand what your code is doing, then enable yourself to see what is going on. Either by adding more print statements, or by running a debugger. Like: print "lines". Print the elements of pair in each loop iteration, and so on. Also note that a map is insufficient here, or what do you expect to happen when forward shows up 5 times? Your map will only keep the last value, and forget about the ones you previously added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can calculate what you indicate in the comments.

```
public void depthPosition() throws IOException {
    int value = 5;
    List<Instruction> instructions = readInstructionsFromFile("/Users/WorkAcc/Desktop/file.txt");
    int result = calculateDepthPosition(instructions, value);
    System.out.println("result is: "+result);
}

private List<Instruction> readInstructionsFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line;
    Instruction instruction;
    List<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] pair;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        pair = line.split(" ");
        instruction = new Instruction(pair[0], Integer.valueOf(pair[1]));
        instructions.add(instruction);
    }
    return instructions;
}

private int calculateDepthPosition(List<Instruction> instructions, int value){
    int nextValue = value;
    int result = value;
    for (Instruction instruction : instructions) {
        nextValue = instruction.apply(nextValue);
        result = Math.min(result, nextValue);
    }
    return result;
}

public static class Instruction {

    private String type;
    private int amount;

    public Instruction(String type, int amount) {
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int apply(int value) {
        switch (type) {
            case "forward":
                return value + amount;
            case "down":
                return value - amount;
            case "up":
                return value ?? amount;
            default:
                return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, duplicate keys are not permitted in maps.

If you want to read in those strings and maintain order (which would seem likely), you can do it like this.

- create a `record` (immutable class) to hold the direction and amount. A regular class could also be used.
- instantiate a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) to read the file (I am reading from a String for demo purposes).
- create a `List` to hold the records. In this case an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--)
- then iterate over the file as follows.

```
String s  = "forward 5\n up 4\n down 3\n down 6\n forward 4\n";

record Info(String direction, int amount){
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[%s, %s]".formatted(direction, amount);
    }
}
Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
List<Info> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(new Info(input.next(), input.nextInt()));
    input.nextLine();  // consume end of line marker
} while(input.hasNextLine());

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[forward, 5]
[up, 4]
[down, 3]
[down, 6]
[forward, 4]
```

You can also interate and get the individual values like so.

```
for (Info info : list) {
  System.out.println(info.direction() + " " + info.amount());
}
```

prints

```
forward 5
up 4
down 3
down 6
forward 4
```

Note: The above solution presumes each line is well defined and contains a `String` and an `int` per line, separate by one or more spaces.  Otherwise, an exception would likely be thrown.

**Updated**

> Once I store the above data, I want to read it in order and do calculations based on the first parameter eg if forward then I add to the number, if down then I subtract from the number etc.

Based on the above added comment you can do it like the following (you may have to adjust the commands somewhat to fit your file).

You can also achieve the following result by iterating of the `list` created above and processing each line in a switch statement.

- create a map to hold the values.
- use `Files.lines` to stream the lines for processing
- using [mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) to process each line.

  - first split into a two parts
  - capture the count and the direction
  - if the direction is down, convert to up and change the sign.
  - for positive directions, use as is. (Note. no counter direction given for `forward`
  - then create a Map entry and insert into the stream.
- collect in a map, summing the values

```
Map<String,Integer> map = null;
try {
map = Files.lines(Path.of("f:/inputFile.txt"))
        .<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>mapMulti((str, consumer) -> {
            String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
            int count = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry =
                    switch (arr[0]) {
                case "forward","up"-> Map.entry(arr[0],
                        count);
                case "down" -> Map.entry("up", -count);
                default -> Map.entry("up, 0); // innocuous entry.
            };
            consumer.accept(entry);
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, Integer::sum));
                
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints (the positive directions are used as keys).

```
forward=9
up=-5
```

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the comments you provided.